# Homebrew services - how to stream its log?

Tags: terminal, homebrew

If I run a command line service like `mongod` , my terminal window will continue to show its log output. If i run it as a homebrew service, which is what mongodb itself recommends for mac, with command `brew services start mongodb-community`, I won't get any log output.

How do i continually stream the log? For mongod, or other homebrew services?

Comment: You mustn't confuse *service* and *homebrew service*. AFAIK each "homebrew service" started with `homebrew service ...` has an own log file (depends on the launch agent/daemon plist provided by the package) and is rather *launchd* related.

Answer (score 8):

The mongodb-community service logs to the following places:

```
$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/var/log/mongodb/output.log
```

Usually this means that they're located in:

```
/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/
```

You can continually stream the logs using a command like this in the Terminal:

```
tail -f /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/*.log
```

Comment: `tail -f *.log` of couuurse :)

Answer (score 0):

You have several options to start mongodb **and** show the mongo log:

1. Directly in the Terminal window:

   ```
   brew services start mongodb/brew/mongodb-community && tail -f -n100 /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
   ```
2. In a second Terminal windows (or a tab) (the second one has to have a known tty device number - you get it e.g. with `w` or `tty`):

   ```
   brew services start mongodb/brew/mongodb-community; tail -f -n100 /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log > /dev/tty001;
   ```
3. Send the log to a detached screen:

   ```
   brew services start mongodb/brew/mongodb-community && screen -dmS mongolog tail -f -n100 /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
   ```

   to attach to the screen use `screen -d -r mongolog` in a second window/tab.